# How to store the number of facebook comments into SQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook supports getting the number of comments on each url by using the following:

```
<fb:comments-count data-href="http://example-url.com"/></fb:comments-count>
```

The problem with this method is that it's working on the user-side and thus the result cannot be stored into SQL.

I'm looking for a method which can run server-side, able to be executed by CRON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with simple FQL query:

```
SELECT commentsbox_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "http://example-url.com"
```

To get this with Graph API use:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=YOUR_QUERY
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the Graph API for this. You can access a JSON-encoded array of a URLs comments by going to, https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}.

If you were using PHP, you could use file_get_contents() to fetch this URL, decode the JSON array and then use count() to get the number of comments. I don't believe that the comments end point is secured by OAuth so you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Comment: This will require paging if large number of comments assigned to this URL. Retrieving all comments is a bit overkill if only number of comments needed, see my answer for simpler solution

Comment: Very true! Your answer is much better.